# Searching documents elasticsearch , fields that contains subvalue for long field

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I want to search for documents in elasticsearch which have a field (registred as long), that contains a sub value,
for example : if i have in my elasticsearch a document that contains (field1 : 12345), and if i search for 12, i should find this document.

```
    {
"_index": "overlog-mouvement-index",
"_type": "_doc",
"_id": "e707b9c1-8fb7-4cca-a659-c1ccdc3ed2f3",
"_version": 1,
"_score": null,
"_source": {
"typeEvent": 0,
"field1": 12345,
},
"sort": [
1633098180340
]
}
```

I am trying to use QueryContainer, that's my code, can u help please with the correct query to use?

```
long tempValue = 12;
 query &= filtreQuery.QueryString(t => t.DefaultField(f => f.field1.ToString()).Query("*" + tempValue.ToString() + "*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a string sub-field into your long field like

```
{
    "field1": {
        "type": "long",
        "fields": {
            "to_string": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, query on the string field, but retrieve the terms aggregations from the long field

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "field1.to_string": "12"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "myAggregation": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1",
        "size": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Note: Not necessary a sub-field, you can also create a completely independent field***